OMML Math to LaTeX conversion
I'm having a Word file with bunch of Math, in which all the equations are setted as in OMML format (MS-Word inbuilt Math format), is this possible to convert the OMML equations to LaTeX format? Please advise.

what would you want to convert only the equations for? note that this probably isn't the best place to ask about word things. (assuming that omml differs from standard mml, as seems highly likely given ms's trackrecord.)

@cfr apology to ask this question here, but I'm sure that I'll get better suggestion, because that much experts are here, and for question, Yes, I need to convert only the Equation part

Did you try Pandoc (from a terminal pandoc -o output.tex input.docx)? It has an OMML reader and writer, which is also available as separate tool (https://github.com/jgm/texmath).

I more meant: why do you want only the equations? and yes, there are plenty of experts here. but the site has a shocking dearth of expertise when it comes to word.
